# ViewModel links record with an array property binded to tagfield triggers dirtyness

Tags: extjs

Using ExtJS 7.3.1.27

I have a Form View which its fields are bound to a record loaded using the ViewModel *links* functionality.

When I open the form, the record is automatically loaded and all fields populated.

One of the fields is a *tagfield* which is also bound to the linked record. Specifically it's bound to a property that holds an array of tags, in this case, the property name is *selected_tags*  .

The tagfield value is bound as usual:

```
bind : {
   store: '{tags}',
   value: '{linked_rec.selected_tags}'
},
```

THe tags are loaded correctly into the tagfield, but the record becomes dirty. This problem only happens with this field.

Is it a ExtJS bug?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a data-binding, it happens in the following order:

- create View
- reset all Fields                ==> not dirty
- ...20 Min later... //asynchronous
- resolve data-binding for tags   ==> dirty

If you want to do it with databinding you have to clear the dirty state for all fields after the data-binding resolves. Personally I am overwrote my fields, so that data-binding works without making the fields dirty.

You might want to go this way =>

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.MainModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.main',
    
    links: {
        formData: {
            type: 'Fiddle.model.Form',
            id: 1
        }
    },
    
    formulas: {
        formDataUpdate: {
            bind: '{formData}',
            get: function(formData) {
                this.getView().loadRecord(formData);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am listening for the links to be resolved and call `loadRecord` to fill the view. This will do the clear dirty job for you.

!! No data binding in the view !!

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, very interesting. Question is, why the problem only happens with tagfield and not the rest of the fields? They are also populated after link resolution and so should become all dirty but they don't, except the tagfield.

Also which is the best way to clear the dirty state for all fields after the data-binding resolves?

Comment: If you setup a fiddle, I will look into the reason behind the problem ;)

Comment: Please add a fiddle (sencha.fiddle.com) so that it is easier to help.